# Storage I/O performance issue

Tags: vsphere, esxi

Our system is using clustering with three hosts but Suddenly Third host's storage performance is super slow can't do anything like 'df -h' command on the host. other two hosts are okay storage performance.

It happened to only third host.

Can you give advice to me how to resolve it?

I already restarted several time the third host but it keep happening to only third host.

Problem

- Can't use any related storage command on cli enviroment such as 'df'.
- Can't migrate to another host but it's working perfectly between first host and second host.
- There isn't any error on third host, vCenter and iLO.

Enviroment

- HPE DL380 G9 Server
- vCenter: 6.7
- vSphere 6.7
- Storage: msa 2050 ssd
- HBA: QLE2692 Dual Port 16Gb Fibre Channel to PCIe Adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem....It was hardware problem.

After moving to another HBA port on Third host, the problem was resolved.

I need to check HBA port problem or FC cable problem.

It was FC gbic problem. After replacing with new fc gbic, the problem resolved.